# printing numpy timedelta64 with format()

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to print a numpy.timedelta64() value in a formatted way. The direct method works well:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print np.timedelta64(10,'m')
10 minutes
```

Which I guess comes from the `__str__`() method

```
>>> np.timedelta64(10,'m').__str__()
'10 minutes'
```

But when I try to print it with the format() function I get the following error:

```
>>> print "my delta is : {delta}".format(delta=np.timedelta64(10,'m'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: don't know how to convert scalar number to long
```

I would like to understand the underlying mechanism of the "string".format() function, and why it doesn't work in this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

falsetru mentions one aspect of the problem. The other is why this errors at all.

Looking at [the code for `__format__`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/04f6c0fe5a80b982f6da88fda47ecf6c05122370/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src#L384), we see that it is a generic implementation.

The important part is:

```
    else if (PyArray_IsScalar(self, Integer)) {
#if defined(NPY_PY3K)
        obj = Py_TYPE(self)->tp_as_number->nb_int(self);
#else
        obj = Py_TYPE(self)->tp_as_number->nb_long(self);
#endif
    }
```

This triggers, and tries to run:

```
int(numpy.timedelta64(10, "m"))
```

but Numpy (rightly) says that you can't convert a number with units to a raw number.

This looks like a bug.

Comment: Do you think I should file a bug report somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Format String Syntax documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> The conversion field causes a type coercion before formatting.
>   Normally, **the job of formatting a value is done by the __format__()
>   method of the value itself.** However, in some cases it is desirable to
>   force a type to be formatted as a string, overriding its own
>   definition of formatting. By converting the value to a string before
>   calling __format__(), the normal formatting logic is bypassed.

```
>>> np.timedelta64(10,'m').__format__('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: don't know how to convert scalar number to long
```

---

By appending [`!s` conversion flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), you can force it to use [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str):

```
>>> "my delta is : {delta!s}".format(delta=np.timedelta64(10,'m'))
'my delta is : 10 minutes'
```

Comment: Thank you falsetru for your solution, I'm using it right now in my code, but I choose Veedrac's answer for going down to the failing line and pointing a potential bug.

Answer (score 1):

`%s` should be fine. It calls `str()` on the object.